# How to check compatible library version interval for my package in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compatibility, python-poetry, tox

I am developing a private python library and I am using other public libraries in it. I want to define an interval of compatible version for every public library that my custom library uses.

I already implemented tests that check if the library works fine. Just need to find a way to test my code in every combination of every public library.

I tried to use tox but it seems like I have to write every combination of libraries in the tox.ini file so that it can create environments with libraries whose versions are different. Is there an automated way to do that?

For example: My development environment has following libraries and it passes my tests.

- numpy==1.24.3
- matplotlib==3.7.3

I want to know if I can test for combinations of

- numpy==1.24.0, 1.24.1 ... 1.24.x
- matplotlib==3.7.1, 3.7.2 ... 3.7.x

in an automated way.

Comment: do you want to check the python version in the python code ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to test with every existing public version for each library in a given range? E.g. `Django~=4.0` --> 4.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, ... 4.0.9, 4.0.10, 4.1, 4.1.1, ... 4.1.12, 4.1.13, 4.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, ... 4.2.8, 4.2.9 + any future 4.2.x?

Comment: Exactly @N1ngu. Do you know any automated way to do that rather than writing every library version into a tox file? I am okey with creating different environments for every version of libraries but writing them does not seem like a good solution.

Comment: Note this is a very uncustomary thing to do and it is unclear in the body of your question, so I'd suggest you edit it because that is not what people will understand.

Comment: As for a solution: again, this is a rare use-case so I doubt an out-of-the box shows up. That makes sense to me because I don't really see the interest in this approach. Even if you achieve it, if you want to vary 2 dependencies you might end with hundreds or thousands of test suite runs for every version combination. Why would anyone want to do that? Is it worth it? Is your test suite so good that this adds any value vs just focusing your efforts in increasing the coverage and verify your mocks?

Comment: I guess I can explain it with an example. Say there is a developer team that creates a project with a python environment of their choice. There is also another team that checks if the first project is working as expected by simulating their project using my custom library. Since the first team is the actual developers, they may want to use different public library versions that I defined in my library. However, second team has to create the same environment with addition of my custom library. Therefore, I want to give an interval of public library versions that I know my library will work.

Comment: I do not think anyone ever does this so thoroughly. -- I believe the common practice is to to list the latest of each major and minor at most (I do not believe it makes sense to list all the maintenace/bugfix releases). -- You can probably write a short script that generates a `tox.ini`. -- Also you might want to have a look at [nox](https://pypi.org/project/nox/), where you can write Python code for the configuration (`noxfile.py`)instead of a static text file (`tox.ini`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who helped me in the comment section. As @sinoroc suggested, using [nox](https://pypi.org/project/nox/) solved my problem in a very intuitive way. Even though this is not a common practice, I am sharing the solution that I used for given example in the question in case if there is anyone who needs to test their project like me.

Codes in the noxfile.py are given below.

```
import nox

@nox.session(name = "test_sample")
@nox.parametrize("numpy", ["1.24.3", "1.24.2"])
@nox.parametrize("matplotlib", ["3.7.3", "3.7.2"])
def tests(session, numpy, matplotlib):
    session.install(f"numpy=={numpy}", f"matplotlib=={matplotlib}")
    session.run("pytest")
```

Parametrize decorator defines the versions that will be used. Since I used two different versions for two different libraries, there will be 4(2*2) test results acquired from different version combinations.

**Note:** I have observed that nox uses python -m pip command to install the libraries. Therefore, if the public libraries that we test have common dependencies between them, there may be an override problem where given version of a library is overwritten while installing another. I could not find a solution for it but this is as precise as version testing can get.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generative environments, described in the documentation of tox, see https://tox.wiki/en/4.12.1/user_guide.html#generative-environment-list

From the documentation:

```
[tox]
env_list = py{311,310,39}-django{41,40}-{sqlite,mysql}

[testenv]
deps =
    django41: Django>=4.1,<4.2
    django40: Django>=4.0,<4.1
    # use PyMySQL if factors "py311" and "mysql" are present in env name
    py311-mysql: PyMySQL
    # use urllib3 if any of "py311" or "py310" are present in env name
    py311,py310: urllib3
    # mocking sqlite on 3.11 and 3.10 if factor "sqlite" is present
    py{311,310}-sqlite: mock
```

Disclaimer: I am one of the tox maintainers. The above section is in the user guide, which just follows the installation instructions. In case you had trouble finding that piece of information, can you tell us how we could improve the documentation?

Comment: Thanks for the response @JürgenGmach . As far as I understand from the documentary, above code creates django41 and django40 environments and uses corresponding django versions. However, inside the django41 environment, there is just one version of the django library(Exp: Such as django 4.1.10). Tox only tests for this version in this environment. I want tox to test every django library version between 4.1.0-4.1.13 etc. Do I have to create a new environment for every library versions? If so, do I have to write every environment name one by one for every version of the library.

Comment: Yes, different versions need different environments. And you are correct, you need to define a marker for each version and then parameterize on that one.